# Sound card "Generic ffff Generic" after hdajackretask

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I have a Thinkpad X1 Carbon with Conexant sound card. It was recognized by my system until I tried to reconfigure the headphone/mic pins with hdajackretask. It now shows "Generic ffff Generic" as the chip name. Also, in pavucontrol the mic is displayed but with no sound input level bar underneath it where it normally would be.

The only other relevant (?) change I made was to disable pulseaudio autospawn.

I have tried `alsactl init` and also purging/reinstalling `pulseaudio` and `alsa*`, as well as removing boot config from hdajackretask. There are no hdajackretask-related files in `/lib/firmware` or `/etc/modprobe.d`.

It seems as though the relevant files in `/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/` have been corrupted to be generic files.

Any suggestions? I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by booting into Windows and reinstalling the appropriate Conexant driver.